# Show directory of people based on state in laravel

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, laravel

**THE GOAL:** In Laravel, show a directory of people by state, showing featured people first.

- I have a page in laravel to show a 'directory' of people from the db
  for each state.
- Some are 'featured', which is a yes/no in the featured column.
- Initially it should show only the featured people
- The user can then select a state from the dropdown, which then shows the people in that state.
- I have a separate table which is a list of state names and abbreviations, so the full state name can appear as the header (not sure if the route should contain a join for the people/states tables)
- For now, I am only able to show the full list of all people, in all states

**This is the current route:**

```html
Route::get('/directory/people', function () {
    $lawyers = DB::table('people_directory')->get();
    return view('pages.directory.people', ['people' => $people]);
});
```

**And in the view:**

```html
<div class="col-md-8">
            
<ul class="nav nav-tabs mb-20">
<li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active" href="">Featured</a></li>
<li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="">Select your state <span class="caret"></span></a>

<!-- state abbreviations list in dropdown -->
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">AK</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">AZ</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">CA</a>
    </div>

</li>
</ul>

<!-- people directory / CONTENT -->
<div id="people-content">

<div class="loading"></div><!-- loading circle for when fetching content -->

<h2>Featured People</h2> <!-- changes to state names -->

@foreach($people as $key => $data)
<div class="card">
<div class="l-name">{{$data->name}}</div>
<div class="l-add">{{$data->address}}</div>
<div class="l-add2">{{$data->city}}, {{$data->state}} {{$data->zip}}</div>
<!-- IF featured --><div>FEATURED</div>
</div>
@endforeach
    
</div>
<!-- /people directory -->

</div><!-- /col -->
```

Any and all help is mucho appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Setup another route for searching by an individual state like so:

```
// assuming your states and abbreviations table is named states
// and you have a foreign key properly setup on people_directory to states
Route::get('/directory/people/{state}', function ($state) {
    $people = DB::table('people_directory')->join('states', 'states.id', '=', 'people_directory.state_id')
                                           ->where('states.name', '=', $state)
                                           ->orderBy('people_directory.featured', 'desc')
                                           ->get();
    return view('pages.directory.people', ['people' => $people]);
});
```

This will give you a listing of people by state in descending order by featured people first.

Comment: How is this supposed to look in the view so the state name is in the title and the correct tab is active?